# Split a String by minus and zero

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

How can a `String` like

```
0.0002230.0012730.000296-0.0014380.0011270.0014690.001457-0.001017`
```

be converted to

```
{0.000223, 0.001273, 0.000296, -0.001438, 0.001127, 0.001469, 0.001457, -0.001017}
```

Comment: `ToExpression[StringCases[yourString, NumberString]]`

Comment: I'd recommend fixing the upstream code that produces this mess; but @yode's solution is great.